# Unable to create partitions using repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, hadoop2

I have an RDD `rddData: RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, String)])]`which is sorted by key and pre splitting region based on Key, `splits: Array[Array[Byte]]`. Following is the code snippet that I used to create partitions using `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` method:

```
 protected abstract class HFilePartitioner extends Partitioner {
    def extractKey(n: Any) = n match {
      case (k: java.lang.String, _) => k
      case (_) => 
    }
}

  class datasetPartitioner(splits: Array[Array[Byte]]) extends HFilePartitioner {   

    override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
      val k = extractKey(key)
      for (i <- 1 until splits.length)
        if (Bytes.compareTo(Bytes.toBytes(k.toString()), splits(i)) < 0) return i - 1

      splits.length - 1
    }
    override def numPartitions: Int = splits.length
  }
```

After invoking the `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` method

```
val partitionedData = rddData.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new datasetPartitioner(splits))
```

I can see that 6 partitions have been created by using `partitionedData.partitions.length`. Then I used `partitionedData.mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, it) =>it.toList.map(x => if (index ==1) {println(x._1)}).iterator).collect` to print which partiton contains which keys but only get all keys for `index == 0`, other partitions do not contain any data. Although 6 partitons have been created but data are not distributed among partitions. I want to distribute data among all partitions.

Comment: TL,DR; why did you written custom partitioner, why not `val partitionedData = rddData.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(splits)` ?

Comment: `splits` is `Array[Array[Byte]]` and `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` method requires `org.apache.spark.Partitioner`.